# TypeError: *.default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a new instance of a class but I for some reason I am getting this error.

`TypeError: jupiterone_client_nodejs_1.default is not a constructor`

How do I fix this?

This is the from the module I am importing

```
declare module "client-nodejs" {
   export default class JupiterClient {
       constructor(options: JupiterClientOptions);
   }
}
```

My index.ts

```
import JupiterClient from 'client-nodejs';
let j1Client = new JupiterClient(j1ClientOptions); //The error is on this line
```

**EDIT**

```
import { JupiterClient } from 'client-nodejs';
```

Gives me an error saying: Module '"client-nodejs"' has no exported member 'JupiterClient'.

Comment: Could you share more code? There should occur no error here.

Comment: I don't have any more code than this.

Comment: This might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553836/10054375

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is this:

```
declare module "client-nodejs" {
   export default class JupiterClient {
       constructor(options: JupiterClientOptions) {} // There was no function body here before.
   }
}
```

If that works, the original way you tried to do the import, `import JupiterClient from 'client-nodejs';` will hopefully work.